# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' error

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Value1,Value2,result,a;

        Console.Write("Enter Value 1: ");
        Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Value 2: ");
        Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Choose an arithmetic operator:");


        Console.WriteLine("\t1. +(add)");
        Console.WriteLine("\t2. -(subtract)");
        Console.WriteLine("\t3. *(multiply)");
        Console.WriteLine("\t4. /(divide)");
        Console.Write("\t5. %(mod)");

        Console.Write("\n\n");

        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (a)
        {
            case"1":
                Console.WriteLine("Operator is: Add");
                result=Value1+Value2;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: "+result);
                break;

            case"2":
                Console.WriteLine("Operator is: Subtract");
                result=Value1-Value2;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: "+result);
                break;

            case"3":
                Console.WriteLine("Operator is: Multiply");
                result=Value1*Value2;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: "+result);
                break;

            case"4":
                Console.WriteLine("Operator is: devide");
                result=Value1/Value2;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: "+result);
                break;

            case"5":
                Console.WriteLine("Operator is: mod");
                result = Value1 % Value2;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: "+result);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

i have basic C# and i try to make a program that can run 5 arithmetic operation using Case Statement, after i complete my coding..i found 5 error that make me stuck..and the output will always come with 2 result(i.e i choose Add..and 2 output will appear,its add and subtract at same time..can someone help me with this?

Comment: Remove the quotation marks around the numbers in your `case` statements. You want to treat them as integers, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending code are your case statements. `a` is an `int`. Your case statements all use `string`s. Simply remove the quotes around the numbers:

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1: 
            // some code
            break;
    case 2: 
            // some code
            break;
    // rest of cases
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i didnt expect that i have error on that quotes because i just follow what in my notes..and inside that notes they put quotes on that Case (i.e case"1":)... thank you again..and now my coding 100% complete. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are converting `a` to an int but your switch statement is matching it to strings. Change it to `case 1:` instead of `case "1"` to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes in case. i.e.

Replace `case "1":` with `case 1:`